# running adb from command line makes the device go offline

Tags: android, adb, ddms

I have a strange problem where everytime I run adb from command line (devices command or pull, or uninstall etc), the device goes offline but if I now go into DDMS in eclipse and reset ADB, it comes back online. If I am running the game from within eclipse, it runs (by which I mean my Eclipse DDMS is able to use adb just fine) but from command line, doing anything adb-related brings the device offline and the only way to bring it back online is adb reset from DDMS inside eclipse. Effectively, I cannot do anything adb-related through command line.

I have tried solutions like switch the debug option of device on and off, adb-kill-server and then start-server, android 51 rules file, and more weirder solutions like change cable, change port etc. Many of those bring the device online, but whenever I run a adb command from the terminal, poof! device is back offline.

I have been facing this for over a month now and I have done all research I could, on google and on stackoverflow but nothing have I found which could address this specific issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue, where, adb will *start* to work through the command line, but a few files into a pull command, etc. it will go back offline. :(

Comment: I have this problem too, with ADK v19. Even turning "do not sleep when connected" on doesn't fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are having two version of `adb` in your computer.
Remove `adb.exe`,`AdbWinApi.dll` and `AdbWinUsbApi` from `C:/Windows` and everything will be fine.

Comment: This may have been your problem, but it's certainly not a general problem. No Android SDK installer puts them in C:\Windows.

Comment: But if you try to use some tool which use there own adb. they place it  in *C:/Windows*.